# What does "sensitive honour" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "man of sensitive honour" mean?

> (...).. the entire loss of his fortune and good name pressing hard and close upon him ; **the man of sensitive honour** , whose difficulties have forced him within sight of (...)

https://books.google.com/books?id=j0QZAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA351&lpg=PA351&dq=sensitivehonour&source=bl&ots=Q3hI6eSd5_&sig=ACfU3U0W_RtW3k3UGuqzo1aBeV5MWsJIRA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjSn9q8-abqAhUPsKQKHVd8A64Q6AEwAHoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=sensitivehonour&f=false

Comment: I'd say it's **sensitive** as in [Quick to detect or respond to slight changes, signals, or influences](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sensitive) - by extension, a person who's both particularly honourable himself, *and* very aware of / easily affected by the [dis]honourable conduct of his peers.

Comment: ...but I wouldn't think too much about the *exact* meaning. No-one really talks like that today (your text is almost two centuries old! :) Just assume ***a man of honour*** and don't worry about what *kind* of "honour" he had.

Comment: ...looking again at the text, I would strongly advise you not to think of it as relevant to learning English in the modern world. It would have been "difficult" (self-indulgently verbose) text even when written. And if you wrote like that today, no-one would bother reading your work even if they *could* understand it.

Comment: Can I ask why you choose to read the extremely obscure Journal *The British Critic and Theological Review* from 1826?  I can't imagine any student thinking that "The repeal of usary laws" looks like an interesting topic.  But nor can I imagine any English teacher suggesting it as a useful source text.    I am genuine curious about the texts that some Language students present on this site.  If I know why you are reading this, I think a clearer answer can be written.

Comment: I am bothered by the notions that nothing written two hundred years ago is worth reading and that the history of ideas is irrelevant to modern thinking, which notions seem to be implied by several of the preceding comments. If one reads the entire article, it seems a very cogent piece of Manchesterism, a line of thought that is still with us although far less popular than two hundred years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a rhetorical usage. The situation being pictured is that of a man anxious to preserve his public reputation but threatened with jail and public humiliation. In other words, "honor" here is meant in the sense of public repute, and "sensitive" means that the specific man being pictured is more sensitive about his public reputation than is usual. (I forget the name of the rhetorical device where an attribute of A is assigned to B.) It is part of a list of examples designed to show that psychologically some prospective debtors are unable to behave rationally and must be protected by the state. As the person who is quoting and disparaging the passage notes, it is a blatant appeal to emotion: we are asked to place ourselves in the psychological shoes of the desperate borrower. The language is that of a sermon, language to which the audience of two centuries ago would have been quite accustomed.

What is being argued is an idea quite popular today and perhaps even true, namely that most people are too incompetent to be left to the dubious mercies of the market, but the argument is dressed in a vocabulary and style that are now long out of date.

Comment: Do you mean that you see "sensitive honor" as a *metonymy*?

Comment: Yes, in this context, I do see it as a kind of metonymy. (Thanks for bringing back the word to me.) That debtor's prison is the "grave of peace and hope" does not imply that the debtor is unusually upright. Nor does simple incapacity to pay imply dishonesty. The whole passage is about people at the end of their tether. Part of the problem here is the shifting meaning of the word "honor." It does not mean to us what it meant four centuries ago, and it probably had dual meanings two centuries ago.

Comment: Quite right.  The phrasing "the certain grave of peace and hope" implies that incarceration would be intolerable, or at least that's what my answer claims.  The part in my answer that implies exceptional honesty for a man of sensitive honor is the phrasing "of even hard, every day honesty" in the newspaper article -- the notion that a man of merely ordinary honestly, *let alone* a man of sensitive honor, would be more forthright than Mr. Tilden seems to have been.

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to compare this use with other times that the phrase was used in the 1800s.   Here's one example:

> So we believe that when Mr. Tilden swears he didn’t know what Felton and Weed and Marble were doing, he swears the truth. He didn’t know. But we are not so sure that a thoroughly conscientious man would accept his construction of the word. He very obviously means that he hadn’t a direct or positive knowledge, like that admitted to a jury in a criminal case, and means nothing else. A man of sensitive honor, of even hard, every day honesty, would mean more than that.

*Indianapolis News*, February 12, 1879

Here, it's clear that "a man of sensitive honor" is someone with integrity, someone of good character, someone honest and forthright and upstanding.   Say, someone for whom failing to do the right thing is a more painful experience.   If his honor is sensitive, then his desire to behave honorably is strong.

> a man of sensitive honor, whose difficulties have forced him within sight of a gaol, to him the certain grave of peace and hope

A *decent* man, threatened with the possibility of intolerable incarceration.

That interpretation seems to fit the passage well.